# What is the equivalent of getWidthPoint() in itextpdf7?

Tags: java, itext, itext7

Upgraded to itextpdf7 and I am using:

```
new Text(" TEST ").setFont(testFont).setFontSize(FONT).setBold().getStrokeWidth();
```

but it always returns null.

With the previous version of itext I was using:

```
new Chunk(" TEST ", FONT_BOLD).getWidthPoint();
```

Is there another way in ItextPdf7 to get the width of a text?

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent is either BaseFont.getWidthPoint(String text, float fontSize) or PdfFont.getWidth(String text, float fontSize).

So you need an instance of a font to start with. It will be easier to use one or the other depending on your context.